# prost crate Message trait function size is really high using rust

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I am using protocol buffer in rust. tokio/prost is a popular one. As I add a simple message like below my binary file size get 7kb bigger. And this is really big amount because of my low flash size(280kb). Any advice to optimize the prost code or the messages.

```
 message MetricLogic{  uint32 id = 1;
  bool is_incremented =2;
  bool is_diff =3;
  LogicType logic_type = 4;
  uint32 metric_id =5;
  ValueConditionGroup statement = 6;
  uint32 factor = 7;
  uint32 offset = 8;
}
```

I need about 30 messages generally but I think I need to merge some to more generag message but I have no idea that what exactly this amount of code comes. The C library was really lighter.

Comment: This may be one-time cost. Have you tried adding two?

Comment: It is possible that adding a second message won't add another 7kB, as the first probably referenced some de/-serializing code which was previously removed when linking. Btw, have you tried some of the tips in [min-sized-rust](https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust)?

Comment: These are the optimizing flags that I have used.

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
opt-level = "s"
lto = "fat"
codegen-units = 1

Comment: The thing is the one-time cost is really high. I have to make it smaller. I want to know tradeoffs.

Comment: I don't think there are any tradeoffs (besides opt-level {s,z,3}, where 3 sometimes is oddly better than z). You can either try one of the other crates (pb-rs (claims to generate small code), protobuf, tobu, …) or do a careful manual implementation.

Comment: @Caesar I don't have any idea about how does proto-buf implementation cost. Do U have any reference or experience ?